# question regarding page size

Tags: unix, operating-system

I have a question How will you determine the page size of a unix machine using C code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getpagesize()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpagesize) or [sysconf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sysconf).